# Microsoft Excel - Macro to copy Invoice data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

Okay so long story short is we are building a completely custom Macro enabled database and invoice system. Presently we have managed to set up the macros for adding new customers, looking up existing customer #'s, creating the invoice with a pop up box to input the customer number which auto populates the customers information into the invoice, a button for adding a product SKU which auto populates the description and pricing.

The main issue we seem to be having is the ability to create a Save Invoice button which copies the cell data from certain cells into a new worksheet.

Pretty much what we want to copy is:

Cells E5 and F5 which are merged cells into the first open space in column A.

Cells E6 and F6 which are merged cells into the first open space in column D.

Cells E7 and F7 which are merged cells into the first open space in column C.

Cells B10 and C10 which are merged cells into the first open space in column B.

Cell G49 into the first open space in column E.

Cell G50 into the first open space in column F.

Cell G51 into the first open space in column G.

The new worksheet that it needs to be copied to is names Invoices and it is being transferred from the Receipt tab by hitting the Save Invoice button.

Comment: "we are building a completely custom Macro enabled database" - so you do it without basic macro knowledge? Do you expect us to do your job? Please note: this is not a free code writing service,  we answer specific questions,  please show what you've tried and describe what's the exact issue with it.

Comment: Copying this into a new sheet, means an empty worksheet? You don't want a header row? You want a new sheet every time you save this? Because that means the first empty row will always be row 1 if you create a new Invoices sheet each time. Are you expecting all of these things in A:G to all be on the same first empty row. Perhaps you can clarify some of this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually what i was asking is not for the exact coding. I have basic knowledge of macro but have never tried actually specifying a single cell out of the whole invoice in my range and doing it multiple times for 1 invoice. I am copying invoice number, xustomer name, customer ID number, date and invoice total out of the invoice into a single worksheet not a new worksheet for a whole invoice as that would be much simpler. Was simply asking for some guidance for specifying multiple single cell ranges within the macro

Comment: And thank you datatoo. I will try that when i get home and then see if i can work out from there how the single cell specifications interact if i need to change it.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are describing.

```
Sub saveButton()
 Set ws = Sheets("Invoices")
 Set rs = Sheets("Receipts")
 LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  ws.Range("A" & LastRow) = rs.Range("E5")
  ws.Range("D" & LastRow) = rs.Range("E6")
  ws.Range("C" & LastRow) = rs.Range("E7")
  ws.Range("B" & LastRow) = rs.Range("B10")
  ws.Range("E" & LastRow) = rs.Range("G49")
  ws.Range("F" & LastRow) = rs.Range("G50")
  ws.Range("G" & LastRow) = rs.Range("G51")
End Sub
```